# show_module tediousness in utop

Tags: ocaml, utop

I am using OCaml utop, with Core.Std module.

To see the help on a module, I have to follow the link of aliases like so:

```
utop # #show_module Array;;
module Array = Core_kernel.Std_kernel.Array                                                                                            

utop # #show_module Core_kernel.Std_kernel.Array;;
module Array = Core_kernel.Std_internal.Array                                                                                          

utop # #show_module Core_kernel.Std_internal.Array;;
module Array = Core_kernel.Core_array
```

And finally show_module on that will show the information. Is there a quicker way?

Comment: Unfortunately I don't think there is. I filed an [issue](http://caml.inria.fr/mantis/view.php?id=7189) upstream.

Comment: Thanks to @gasche, something now already on the way, see https://github.com/ocaml/ocaml/pull/520

Comment: Thanks for reporting this Daniel!

Comment: A compiler repo patch in less than 24 hours, I love this community.

Answer (score 2):

For completeness, the pull request mentioned by Daniel in the comments has been merged since, and now `utop` is smarter when it comes to `#show_module`.

```
utop # #show_module Array;;

module Array = Base__.Array
module Array = Base.Array
module Array :
  sig
    type 'a t = 'a array
    val compare : ('a -> 'a -> int) -> 'a t -> 'a t -> int
    val t_of_sexp : (Sexp.t -> 'a) -> Sexp.t -> 'a t
    val sexp_of_t : ('a -> Sexp.t) -> 'a t -> Sexp.t
    [...]
  end
```